# Route [login] not defined after moving routes folder

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm using Laravel to build an admin site, and need to have all controllers routes models in one folder so i moved the routes and controller to this folder and changed the RouteServiceProvider.php to this:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as 
  ServiceProvider;
 class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
 /**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $namespace = 'App\Application\Controllers';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot()
 {
    //

    parent::boot();
 }

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('app/Application/routes/web.php'));
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('app/Application/routes/api.php'));
}
```

}

it works fine but giving me following error:

Route [login] not defined.

And here is my routes file:

```
 <?php

 Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index');
```

And my home controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
   return view('home');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route file you have just this:

```
 <?php
 Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index');
```

As you can see there is just one routing and that work just for one page, in fact if you want to use from $this->middleware('auth'); you should define routing of that.

something like this:

```
 Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

You denied $this->middleware('auth'); for controller of Home and it is force to find login route to redirect that. so change your constructor to to following code:

```
public function __construct()
{

}
```

Comment: ut i need to use auth for this controller

Comment: So you should define controllers of that, check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication for more information about auth and using of that

Comment: i have had auth folder and it worked before moving the routes now itdon't

Comment: you should have routing rules of AUTH, but it seems there is not, add following code to your route php file and test if you are using default laravel authing system

Auth::routes();

Comment: your welcome i will appreciate if you up-vote and mark as best answer @Radwa Ali